# Differentiability of $f(x,y)=\min\{x,y\}$ at $(1,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have difficulties with this question:

We define the function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=\min\{x,y\}$

Prove, $f$ is partial differentiable at $\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\0\end{array}\right)$ and calculate the partial derivatives of $f$ at point $\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\0\end{array}\right)$.

In another post i found another way of writing the function as:
$$f(x, y) = \min(x,y) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x \le y \\
y & \text{if } x \gt y
\end{cases}$$

But how can i work with this now? This function is different than the others i usually have.

What i also read is:

$$f(x,y) = \min(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2} (x_1 + x_2-|x_1-x_2|)$$

Comment: Just work in the neighborhood $S=B((1,0),1/3)$ where $x>y$ $\forall (x,y)\in S$. So, in this domain $f(x,y) = y$.

Comment: @RafaelGonzalezLopez i tried to understand what you wrote but i dont get it :-/ Is this a Ball with radius 1/3 at point (1,0) ? How does this help me? I have difficulties understand maths. sorry

Comment: Differentiability is a local property. Let $g(x,y)=y$. In the ball, $f(x,y) \equiv g(x,y)$, so you can study the differentiability taking $g(x,y)$ instead of $f(x,y)$, and in $(1,0)$, $g(x,y)$ is obviously differentiable and $g_x(x,y)=0$, $g_y(x,y)=1$ for all $(x,y)\in S$.